# Pandas DF MultiIndex Selection

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame containing experimental results.(Note that it is a dataframe within a dictionary)
The DF head can be seen below:
[image: DF head]

and the tail (it is a long data set):
[image: df tail]

The DataFrame index:
[image: DataFrame Index]
This DataFrame shows two experiments (calibration_type) : sensitivity and selectivity

I can select a 'calibration_type' using x['raw_data_calibration].xs('selectivity').

How do I:

1. Drop the calibration_num column (the 0 or 1 refers to the calibration_type as far as I am aware, all calibration_type=sensitivity entries have a calibration_num=1
2. As can be seen in the following image. The electrode_num refers to 1 of 8 different electrodes in a sensor chip. I would like to group these and transpose them into column headers. So the output DataFrame would have the following columns: electrode_1....electrode_8, raw_time,raw_current[image: electrode num]

Comment: paste real data here would be better. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Drop the calibration_num column (the 0 or 1 refers to the calibration_type as far as I am aware, all calibration_type=sensitivity entries have a calibration_num=1

`x.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

> As can be seen in the following image. The electrode_num refers to 1 of 8 different electrodes in a sensor chip. I would like to group these and transpose them into column headers. So the output DataFrame would have the following columns: electrode_1....electrode_8, raw_time,raw_current

`x.unstack(level=-1)`
With that you will get a MultiIndex column-wise with first level electrode_1...electrode_8 as first level and raw_time..boundary as second level

(Chain the two functions for combining both effects)